# Pointer on class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby model I want to apply default value on somes properties on my `Recipe`. So I added an `before_save` callback to apply it: This is my Recipe model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :set_default_time

    # other stuff

    private

    # set default time on t_baking, t_cooling, t_cooking, t_rest if not already set
    def set_default_time
        zero_time = Time.new 2000, 1 ,1,0,0,0

        self.t_baking   = zero_time unless self.t_baking.present?
        self.t_cooling  = zero_time unless self.t_cooling.present?
        self.t_cooking  = zero_time unless self.t_cooking.present?
        self.t_rest     = zero_time unless self.t_rest.present?
    end

end
```

It's pretty work but I want to factorize it like this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :set_default_time

    # other stuff

    private

    # set default time on t_baking, t_cooling, t_cooking, t_rest if not already set
    def set_default_time
        zero_time = Time.new 2000, 1 ,1,0,0,0

        [self.t_baking, self.t_cooling, self.t_cooking, self.t_rest].each{ |t_time|
            t_time = zero_time unless t_time.present?
        }

    end

end
```

But it doesn't work. How can I loop on "pointer" on my object propertie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it won't work because you refer strictly to value, thus your override doesn't work as expected. you may try this:

```
[:t_baking, :t_cooling, :t_cooking, :t_rest].each { |t_time|
  self.send("#{t_time}=".to_sym, zero_time) unless self.send(t_time).present?
}
```

Comment: Nice, one little trick is that you can skip casting the method name to a symbol, `.send` works perfectly fine with a string.

Comment: true, but using symbols is a bit more efficient as far as I know. The thing is if you have symbol `:foobar` in different places in your app they have the same `object_id`, which is not true for strings (double memory allocation)

Comment: @djaszczurowski: But you are creating the strings anyway, in order to call `to_sym` on them.